# Does c++0x tuple use the new variadic templates or Boost's macro-fied tuple implementation?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, tuples, variadic

I read it was *based* on Boost's version, but I wasn't quite sure what that meant when it came down to implementation.  I know Boost does their own variadic template, but I would assume c++0x would use its own variadic templates for the new tuple.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `tuple` in the C++0x draft standard uses C++0x variadic templates.  It is declared as (§20.4.1):

```
template <class... Types> class tuple;
```

Note, however, that the TR1 language extensions also include `tuple`, which does not use variadic templates, since there was no such thing when TR1 was written.  In TR1, `tuple` is declared as (§6.1):

```
template <class T1 = unspecified ,
          class T2 = unspecified ,
          ...,
          class TM = unspecified > class tuple;
```

where `M` is some implementation-defined value that should be at least ten.

TR1 isn't formally a part of the C++ language, but many recent implementations support it.  If you have an implementation that doesn't yet support variadic templates, it might support the TR1 `tuple`.

You can download the latest draft standard, the [Final Committee Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2010/n3092.pdf) (10.5 MB PDF link).

Comment: Thanks!  That clarifies it.  Thanks for the link too.